# Jquery Dialog load contents on database mysql or ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dialog

I have a view page which as list of records of submitted forms. I want to have a link on each record and whenever you click it, a jquery dialog box will appear containing the information of that clicked record. Here's my loop for the list.

```
 for($a=0;$a<$size;$a++)
{
$tabletr .= "<tr>      
              <td ><a href=''> ".$arr[$a][1] . ", " . $arr[$a][2] ."<a/> </td>
            </tr>";
}
```

Can you give me idea how can do it? Thanks!

Comment: This link may be helpful http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/

Answer (score 0):

u can use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ to create a Dialog box. then declare a JS Function like

```
showDialog(){
//your dialog with information
};
```

then added JS function to your loop

```
$tabletr .= "<tr>      
          <td ><a href='javascript: showDialog();'> ".$arr[$a][1] . ", " . $arr[$a][2] ."<a/> </td>
        </tr>";
```

Comment: How could I get the content of my record to javascript?

Comment: u can get your record result with ajax in JS